# Get pending friend requests from one table

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

Im trying to get all pending friend requests from a table with schema:

| id | user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- | --- |

A pending request would just be a single row such as:

(Meaning user 1 sent a request to user 2)

| id | user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

and when accepted it becomes two rows, and I am able to join two of this table to find all accepted (this is working just fine).

An accepted request for reference:

| id | user_id | friend_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

My accepted query looks like this (Im using bookshelf js and knex.js):

```
const friends = new Friends();
    return friends.query((qb) => {
        qb.select('friends.user_id', 'friends.friend_id');
        qb.join('friends as friendsTwo', 'friends.user_id', 'friendsTwo.friend_id');
        qb.where('friends.user_id', '=', id);
    }).fetchAll();
```

How can I modify this to only get the one way relationships?
My first thought was leftJoin and I couldnt seem to get it to work, so if anyone knows an answer or has seen a good answer please lead me to it, thanks :).

Comment: This has nothing to do with `node.js` or `bookshelf.js`, please edit your question to remove irrelevant tags.

Comment: This approach of creating entries in db for a single friend request is a nasty approach. You should create another column called `is_accepted` that contains the status of the friend request in it. This way you create an entry whenever a new friend request is sent and just update the same when the request is accepted. Improve the db structure while you can or else it will cause issue when you have a larger data set once you've deployed to production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can completely go away from idea of join in this project. I had done something similar in my previous projects and I think it will be best to add a third field `isMutual` meaning if they are mutual or not. The field is self-explanatory and  think you got the idea. After that your table must look like

#### No accepted friendship

| id | user_id | friend_id | isMutual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | false |

#### Accepted friendship

| id | user_id | friend_id | isMutual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | true |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | true |

I believe doing this will actually benefit your system as your query will be faster and try making an `compound index for (user_id, friend_id)`. This solution is more towards shifting the load.

### Conclusion

Using this, you can achieve faster queries, but all the hard work done in during `READ OPERATION` in previous schema will shift to `WRITE OPERATION`.
But I think this will reduce writing speed by more.
And yeah, make sure you use transaction doing updates for `isMutual` field.

Comment: Well, this approach can even be improved further by just having one single record for a particular friend request and every time a request is accepted just put a boolean against a another column called `is_accepted`. I don't really understand why two entries are made for a single friend request. That will just store redundant data in the db.

Comment: I did that for compound indexes. I agree on ** That will just store redundant data in the db **. But I think that writing off the 2nd entry would make it hard to query `SLOWER READ`. As using queries like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE user_id=1 OR friend_id=1` would ** increase COST of read operation. **

Saying as a Postgres based Developer

Comment: @Salvino - Because when querying for a list of user's friends you just have `WHERE friend_id = ?` *(index seek)* rather than `WHERE friend_id = ? OR user_id = ?` *(table scan)*.  It ***is*** a standard approach.

Comment: I don't think A `user_id` will always stay in `friend_id` column. It could be anywhere in `friend_id` or `user_id` depending upon who initiated the `WRITE` operation.

Comment: @MatBailie with my suggested approach, you can query the pending requests with `WHERE user_id=X AND is_accepted=0`. I'm not sure what exactly you meant by your previous comment? why are two entries maintained for the same friend request?

Comment: Oh, I got your idea. I think mine sticks best when there is followers followings like Instagram type of model. But your comment should cover some weaknesses in my implementation. Your idea should work well in friends system like facebook. `Learned something new. Thankyou`

Comment: @Salvino - You questioned why maintain two records.  I gave a scenario whereby the system queries for all the friends of one specific user.  If I request to befriend Nirjal, and it is accepted, my id is in the `user_id` column.  But if you request to befriend me and it is accepted, my id is in the `friend_id` column.   This means that to get a full list of my friends I need to query both columns `WHERE friend_id = Mat OR user_id = Mat`, a scan rather than a seek.  Maintaining both directions means that only one column ever needs to be queried.  It's the equivalent to doubly linked lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
qb.leftJoin('friends as friendsTwo', 'friends.user_id', 'friendsTwo.friend_id');
qb.whereNull('friendsTwo.user_id');
```

This will `LEFT JOIN`, which keeps all rows (pending or accepted), but then filter to keep only those with no matching record in `friendsTwo`; thus returning only the pending links.